# Output SQL Results into a 2 Column Table in MS Word

Tags: javascript, ms-word

I really need your help.

I am designing an HTA and I would like to have the code amended below, such that I would be able to output SQL recordset results broken down in a 2 column table using MS Word. It also seems that current code inserts a blank row. How do I also get rid of that?

Here is the code in question:

```
function test() {



        var wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application")
        var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add()

        doc.Tables.Add(Range=doc.Range(0, 0), numrows=1, numcolumns=2)
        doc.Tables(1).Borders.Enable = true

        i = 1
        while (!rs.eof) {

            doc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells.Add()

            doc.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells(i + 1).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value

            i++
            rs.movenext
        }

        wordApp.Visible = true
        wordApp.Activate();
        //wordApp.WindowState = 1
}
```

And here is screen grab of the problem and the expected result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function test() {

        var wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application")
        var doc = wordApp.Documents.Add()
        var col

        doc.Tables.Add(Range=doc.Range(0, 0), numrows=1, numcolumns=2)
        doc.Tables(1).Borders.Enable = true

        row = 1
        col = 0
        while (!rs.eof) {

            col = col + 1

            alert(row)

            if (col = 1) {
                doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,1).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
                col = col + 1
                rs.movenext
            }
            if (col = 2) {

                if (rs.AbsolutePosition < rs.RecordCount) {            
                    doc.Tables(1).Rows.Add()
                }
                doc.Tables(1).Cell(row,2).Range.Text = rs.Fields("firstname").value
                col = 1
                rs.movenext
            }

            row++
        }

        wordApp.Visible = true
        wordApp.Activate();
        //wordApp.WindowState = 1
}
```